# How to model wavy pattern on the surface?

Tags: modeling

G'day to all B3D community!

I started working on the project to model fitness bracelet and have no any idea how to model wavy pattern on the surface! Maybe you, guys, know some ways of doing that?

I've attached an image of what I'm talking about! [image]

Thanx a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

### Sketch curve, convert to mesh and then refine.

**Sketch pattern main feature:**

I would start from the sketching the main lines of the pattern using a **bezier curve**. First thing to place are the start and end point. Grab them around upon a reference image. Then adjust the handles orientation to match the reference curve's tangency (vertical) like the image below is showing:

[image].

**Create main geometry**

Now that we have the curve, set a **bevel object** (the black arrow in the picture is pointing mine) to place some faces to work with. At this point you can temporarily add modifiers to the object to get an idea of the final apparence of the pattern:

[image]

**Convert to mesh and edit the object**

As for the final model I plan to use the subdivision surface modifier, I kept the curve's resolution low before **converting the curve to mesh**. After this, run the **symmetrize** command to mirror and duplicate the mesh around the origin. Then clean up a bit the model by **deleting** unecessary faces:

[image]

You'll have to repeat the operation to take care of the border in order to achieve a fully tileable mesh. Fill the voids with the faces paying attention to not work outside the imaginary boundaries of the figure. You should come up with something similar to the image below:

[image]

**Final retouches and modifiers**

Now that the basic shape is ready you can **tweak** each **vertex** position manually, with proportional edit enabled, or even with the sculpting tools, or using the smooth vertex command... in order to achieve the right shape. You can also **alter** the **topology** with the knife tool, edge collapsing, deleting and creating faces... till you reach a satifying result.

[image]

Comment: G'day Carlo! Thanx a lot for your help! Your and Tooniis's answers gave me good lessons of how to think outside the box! I have some small stuff left to fix, but I think I can do it myself...

Comment: G'day Carlo! Looks like I really need extra-help for this one.... It is just a test modelling.... I did as you advised, then I applied Array and Curve modifiers.... By the end - shape of this bracelet came with some artifacts and not smooth... So, my question is - how to make that shape smooth along its shape? I have an image of what I mean, but I don't know how to attach it to my comment here.

Comment: You can upload the image somwhere and post the link, or even start a new question, as the problem now involves arrays, smoothing, and artifacts, not patterns. BTW, for the moment I can only guess that maybe you are not merging arrays elements correctly.

Comment: Ahh! Ok.... not merging arrays elements correctly...Ok, as you said - it is easier to start new question and upload my image! Thanx for you help - gave me something to think about!

Answer (score -1):

Create a similar texture (in GIMP or other image processing software) then add an image texture node to the material and connect it to the displacement in the last node.
This will help you if you are using cycles. I don't know how to do it in the internal engine.

Comment: Thanx, mate! I was thinking about that....but decided use only Blender modelling techniques to deal with that stuff, but stuck.... I'll try what you suggested! :)